# Overflow error decoding transfer raw data

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

I want to decode Tron TRC20 transfer without using getEventByTransactionID, i tried the method found [here](https://developers.tron.network/docs/parameter-encoding-and-decoding): but i am getting this:

[
'41lue exceeds width (20 bits) (operation="tobehex", fault="overflow", value=95342449491495438414145500878006688003189807677987, code=numeric_fault, version=6.6.4)',
63n
]

raw_data:

```
    const raw_data= 'a9059cbb0000000000000000000000413c674c3f07c94b53f1cd2bd5d88d0e1655ea8223000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003f'
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to decode it, should always work?

```
function decode(data: string) {
const transferMethodId = "a9059cbb";
const methodId = data.slice(0, 8);
if (transferMethodId == methodId) {
  const toInHex = "0x" + data.slice(32, 72);
  const to = provider.address.fromHex(toInHex);
  const amountHex = "0x" + data.slice(72);
  const amount = ethers.toBigInt(amountHex).toString();
  return {
    amount,
    to,
  };
}
```

}